# How to make values of a Spark Dataset Average column add up to 1?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I calculate the average of a column of a dataset using:

```
val averageDS = firstDS
          .filter(dateFilter)
          .groupBy("id", "lifespan")
          .agg(avg("rate") as "value")
```

This dataset contains:

```
+-------------------+--------+--------------------+
|id                 |lifespan|value               |
+-------------------+--------+--------------------+
|3747824            |19      |0.026000000000000002|
|3747824            |2       |0.06799999999999999 |
|3747824            |25      |0.0                 |
|3747824            |0       |0.502               |
|3747824            |23      |0.0                 |
|3747824            |21      |0.0                 |
|3747824            |22      |0.0                 |
|3747824            |9       |0.002               |
|3747824            |24      |0.0                 |
|3747824            |5       |0.024               |
|3747824            |17      |0.0                 |
|3747824            |20      |0.0                 |
|3747824            |12      |0.0                 |
|3747824            |6       |0.014000000000000002|
|3747824            |11      |0.0                 |
|3747824            |3       |0.082               |
|3747824            |8       |0.02                |
|3747824            |7       |0.006               |
|3747824            |4       |0.08600000000000001 |
|3747824            |10      |0.022               |
+-------------------+--------+--------------------+
```

The values will not add up to exactly 1 due to the precision issues (in this example the sum is 1.002)

Is there any way to change this dataset so that they add up to 1? I tried to implement the [Largest remainder method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Largest_remainder_method) but I didn't succeed. I did it for a list of values but didn't succeed for a dataset column.

For a list of values, this works fine (The values will add up to 100%):

```
def roundMapValues(ratePerLifespane: Map[Int, BigDecimal]): Map[Int, Double] = {
        val sortedMapByValues = ListMap(ratePerLifespane.toSeq.sortWith((a, b) => a._2.-(a._2.intValue())  > b._2.-(b._2.intValue())):_*)
        val diff = Math.abs(ratePerLifespane.values.map(value => value.intValue()).sum.-(100).intValue())
        sortedMapByValues.zipWithIndex.map {
            case (x, i) =>
                if (i < diff) (x._1, (x._2.intValue() + 1) / 100D) else (x._1, x._2./(100).setScale(2, FLOOR).doubleValue())
        }
    }
```

But I cannot do the same for a column using Spark.

Thank you!

Comment: If you would like help with a Spark implementation of the largest remainder method, it would be helpful to see your attempt that didn't succeed. Either the list version or the column version. This will help us give specific feedback on where the problem is.

Comment: I added my solution for a list of values, but I didn't find a way to do it using Spark.